# Ansible GCP j2 template with nested variables and lookup vars

Tags: templates, google-cloud-platform, ansible, jinja2, roles

I am trying to template a startup script for an app in GCP. The environment uses GCP dynamic inventory for Ansible.  I need to pull a var from group_vars and put it into a {{ }} string in my template. The playbook runs as a role and the template file looks like this:

`export CLOUD5_DB_HOST={{ groups["lookup('vars', project_short_name)_schema_inboxdb"][0] }}`

My group_vars for this inventory group looks like this:

group_vars:
`project_short_name: demo8`

I need this template to produce this string:
"demo8_schema_inboxdb"

If I wrap the template string in double quotes as above, I get:
"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute "lookup('vars', project_short_name)_schema_inboxdb""}

If I remove the double quote and try it like this:
`export CLOUD5_DB_HOST={{ groups[lookup('vars', project_short_name)_schema_inboxdb][0] }}`

I get
"AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ',', got '_schema_inboxdb'.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong with these var lookups ?

Comment: You should mention (and update the tag) what GCP product you're using to help the community, have more clarity to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about `lookup('vars')` vs string formatting.
I was able to get the desired results with string formatting and did not need the `lookup(vars)`

template file works like this:
`export DB_HOST={{ groups[project_short_name + '_schema_inboxdb'][0]  }}`